# Python changing folder permissions

Tags: python

for some reason this python script no longer works now. The script changes the folder permission to read only after it has been run? It runs once and deletes all the files in the folder but when it runs again it gets a Windows error 5 Access denied due to the script changing the permissions to read only on the folder. I can't see why it does this or how to avoid it?

The thing is i didn't write this script and know nothing about python. how would you change it to avoid this issue. Please could you give an example with the code in the script, i wouldn't know where to place it. thanks for the help!

```
import os
import shutil

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(eg.globals.tvzip):
    for f in files:
        os.remove(os.path.join(root, f))
    for d in dirs:
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root, d))

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(eg.globals.tvproc):
    for f in files:
        os.remove(os.path.join(root, f))
    for d in dirs:
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root, d))
```

Comment: Same question asked yesterday...

Comment: And they both seem to be the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728852/shutil-rmtree-raises-exception-windowserror-access-is-denied.

Comment: What reason do you have to believe the files were changed to read-only? As you were told in both of the previous questions, you can _also_ get this error in Windows if any program has one of the files open (with default sharing permissions) when you try to delete it. And it's not even impossible, given the bizarre way you're walking things and trying to delete them out from under yourself, that "any program" is your own script.

Comment: yes, same question but i didn't make clear i literally have no idea about python. i have no idea how to insert your suggestions. i was hoping someone could post their idea with their code inserted. i followed this guide: http://www.totalhtpc.com/automated-media-center-using-xbmc-and-torrents/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't care whether you wrote this code or not, it makes no sense, and trying to make it work without fixing it is a silly idea.

First, if you want to remove an entire directory tree, don't try to walk the tree and remove each subtree before walking it. Just remove the whole tree:

```
shutil.rmtree(eg.globals.tvzip)
shutil.rmtree(eg.globals.tvproc)
```

If you want to remove all of the contents of the tree, but not the root itself, don't use `os.walk`, just `os.listdir`:

```
for p in os.listdir(eg.globals.tvzip):
    shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(eg.globals.tvzip, p)
for p in os.listdir(eg.globals.tvproc):
    shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(eg.globals.tvproc, p)
```

That will remove any errors caused by your code stepping on its *own* toes, trying to keep a directory open for its walk and trying to delete it at the same time.

If you still get errors, it *could* be because some of the files are read-only, but it could just as easily be because some other program has them open. The only way you will be able to debug that is to know *which* files, so you can examine them.

The exceptions that you get should include the full pathname to the file that failed in their output—in fact, you showed one in one of your other questions:

```
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\zDump\\TVzip\\Elem.avi'
```

So, how do you know what the problem is?

You can open `C:\zDump\TVzip` in Explorer and look at Elem.avi and see if it's read-only. Or you can use the DOS prompt, if you know how to do that.

To determine whether it's being kept open by another program, you need a third-party tool. The GUI tool [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and the command-line tool [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx), both from Sysinternals and published by Microsoft, are probably the simplest.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for this. With this i'll get to the bottom of it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a whole tree of flies, `shutil.rmtree` will do it for you - you don't need to walk the list of files deleting them.

If you're trying to not delete the top level directory, you should add a check for that. According to the docs, you will be given the top-level directory:

> os.walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False)
>
> Generate
>   the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down
>   or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top
>   **(including top itself)**, it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames,
>   filenames).

Could something else than your script be setting these folders read only? Perhaps you're deleting them, then getting Access Denied because they don't exist, or something else is re-creating them that way?